# Software to make a certain program always minimize to tray?

Tags: windows, window-manager

I would like to be able to set a certain program to always minimize to the system tray when I click the minimize button in the title bar. I've found programs that would accomplish this using extra menus or keyboard shortcuts, but this isn't what I'm looking for - I want it to work when clicking on the minimize button.

4T Tray Minimizer can do this, but only in the paid version, which is $20.

I should mention that the program in question is a standalone Chrome app.

Is there a free or cheaper Windows program that could help me accomplish this?

Comment: There is [simiar question on superuser](http://superuser.com/q/132661/287473) asked before this site was born.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RBTRAY](http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/) does the work for you without adding any extra menu or shortcut or buttons. You just need to right click the minimize button to minimize the application to System Tray.

In the system tray, you can left click the icon to open the app, right click to close it. You can add a shortcut of the program in the startup folder and it will start automatically upon system booting.

To go to startup folder, goto **run** -> **shell:startup** and paste the shortcut there. Or open Windows Explorer and in the address bar give the command shell:startup and paste the shortcut over there.

Comment: Thanks, RBTray is good enough, even if it works via right-click.

Comment: Thanks. Activation using right click is actually an advantage, because I can still choose between original and new behavior of minimize button.

Comment: a useful update if you want to add it is that a new user on GitHub has taken over RbTray with recent updates - per: https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/7fvptz/comment/i5wtttl/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 --- >>> https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray